# Asp.net Boilerplate - Implement setting manager with database

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've been building an asp.net core website, using the asp.net boilerplate template.   As of now, I've been storing all of the settings in the appsettings.json file.  As the application gets bigger, I'm thinking I should start storing some settings via ABP's SettingProvider and ISettingStore.

My question is, does anyone have, or know of, a sample application that show's how to implement ISettingStore and storing the settings in the database?

The only post I could find so far is [this](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero/issues/43), but the link hikalkan supplies is broken.

Thanks for any help,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

ABP stores settings on memory with default values. When you insert a new setting value into database, then it reads from database and overrides the default value. So basically when database has no settings then it means all the settings are on default values. Setting values are stored in AbpSettings table. 
To start using settings mechanism. Create your own SettingProvider inherited from SettingProvider. Initialize it in your module (eg: 
ModuleZeroSampleProjectApplicationModule). 
As SettingProvider is automatically registed to dependency injection; You can inject ISettingManager wherever you want.

```
public class MySettingProvider : SettingProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<SettingDefinition> GetSettingDefinitions(SettingDefinitionProviderContext context)
    {
        return new[]
                {
                    new SettingDefinition(
                        "SmtpServerAddress",
                        "127.0.0.1"
                        ),

                    new SettingDefinition(
                        "PassiveUsersCanNotLogin",
                        "true",
                        scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant
                        ),

                    new SettingDefinition(
                        "SiteColorPreference",
                        "red",
                        scopes: SettingScopes.User,
                        isVisibleToClients: true
                        )

                };
    }
}
```

In application services and controllers you don't need to inject ISettingManager 
 (because there's already property injected) and you can directly use SettingManager property. Forexample :

```
   //Getting a boolean value (async call)
    var value1 = await SettingManager.GetSettingValueAsync<bool>("PassiveUsersCanNotLogin");
```

And for the other classes (like Domain Services) can inject ISettingManager

```
   public class UserEmailer :  ITransientDependency
   {

            private readonly ISettingManager _settingManager;

            public UserEmailer(ISettingManager settingManager)
            {
                _settingManager = settingManager;            
            }

            [UnitOfWork]
            public virtual async Task TestMethod()
            {
                 var settingValue = _settingManager.GetSettingValueForUser("SmtpServerAddress", tenantAdmin.TenantId, tenantAdmin.Id);
            }
   }
```

Note: To modify a setting you can use these methods in SettingManager   **ChangeSettingForApplicationAsync**, **ChangeSettingForTenantAsync** and **ChangeSettingForUserAsync**

Comment: For the AbpSettings table,  do I have to create that in my code-first classes?   
I wasn't able to find any documentation on the ABP website concerning that table.

Comment: you don't need to create class for settings table. You don't need to modify that table. As I showed you, you have to use SettingManager to get and change values. And MySettingProvider to create new settings. So that's it. It's very simple. I added method names to change setting value in the end of my answer. (By the way, accept my answer if it's ok!)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't quite understand how it can save to the database.  There is no AbpSettings table in my database,  and I'm using the ABP project template.   I don't understand how the SettingManager can save/update settings to the AbpSettings table that does not exist.   I currently do have a class implementing the settingmanager, but for now it's just hard coded values, returning an array of SettingDefinitions, as the example shows in the ABP documentation.

Comment: so you have a different problem with migratons. be sure all the migrations applied successfully. There must be settings table

Comment: By default, the ABP project template does not have a AbpSettings DbSet in the EF context file.  Do I need to add it?  Something like this?

public DbSet<SettingDefinition> AbpSettings { get; set; }

Comment: I think I figured out the disconnect here.  I'm working with the basic free ABP template, not the module-zero template.  According to the Setting Management documentation on ABP's site, only the module-zero template comes with the setting system fully implemented by default.  In the free template, it seems you need to create your own implementation.

Comment: yes, right. Module zero has included Setting Management (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management)

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu: Alper, I have added code for Currency setting and it's for tenants, now in client side I can access default value only, my question is how can we set multiple values to Currecny setting? and is there UI component for it anywhere?

Comment: maybe you can ask this a new question. it'll be more useful for the newcomers

Comment: any help on this? i'm trying to implement db settings for abp too and have got no clue on how to proceed, and documentation is not helping